# SIgnature of bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, bilinear-form

I've been solving the following problem on symmetrical bilinear forms:

Let $V$ a $\mathbb R$-vector space of dimension $n$ and $ f_1, f_2 \in V^\ast$ two non-zero linear functionals such that $f_1$ is not a scalar multiple of $f_2$. Define the application $f:V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by:

$$f(u, v):= \frac{f_1(u)f_2(v)+f_2(u)f_1(v)}{2}.$$

Of course $f$ is a symmetrical bilinear form. What I don't know what to do is determine the signature of $f$. In fact, I believe that you need to compute the matrix of $f$ in some basis, and after that, find a diagonal matrix similar to the matrix of $f$ (it always exists). After that, count the number of negative and positive terms on the diagonal (which is always equal, by Sylvester's law of inertia).

However, I was a little confused on how to do this. My question would be: am I on the right path? Is there any simpler way to find the signature?

Also, I was stuck trying to follow after building the matrix of $f$ on some basis. If anyone could continue with any tips, i would be very grateful.

Comment: Is this problem from a specific book? if so can you tell me its name please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Take $\mathcal B =\{e_1, e_2, e_3, \dots,e_n \}$ as a basis of $V$ where $\operatorname{span}\{e_3, \dots, e_n\} =\ker f_1 \cap \ker f_2$ and $f_1(e_1) =f_2(e_2)=1$. This is possible considering the given hypothesis.

In $\mathcal B$, the matrix of $f$ is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1/2 & 0 &\cdots &0\\
1/2 & 0 & 0 &\cdots &0\\
0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots &0\\
\vdots & \vdots
 & \vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
0 & \cdots & 0 &\cdots &0\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$ You’ll get that signature is $1,-1,0, \dots ,0$.

Comment: Very nice and elegant solution

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Incredible. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please elaborate as to why $ \operatorname{span}\{e_3, \dots, e_n\} =\ker f_1 \cap \ker f_2 $ ? why you can choose such a basis? in other words, why $ \dim ( \ker f_1 \cap \ker f_2  ) = n-2  $?

Comment: @hazelnut_116 This is a consequence of the general formula $\dim (U+ V) = \dim U + \dim V - \dim U \cap V$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace#Operations_and_relations_on_subspaces) for details.